# How to return more than one type from a function?

Tags: c++, function, return, arguments

The backstory.
In VBA in Excel I created a function that calculate the shortest distance between two lines (vectors). This function returns the apparent intersection point, and the actual distance between them.
To make this work I ended up passing out an array, then sorting out what went where afterwards. It works, but is clunky to read and work with.

In C++ i have made a similar function that returns the point in question.

```
struct point3D
{ 
double x,y,z;
}
point3D findIntersect(const vec3& vector1, const vec3& vector2)
{
// Do stuff...
return point;
}
```

The problem:
I want to return the length as well, since it uses parts of the original calculation. However most of the time I only want the point.

Possible solutions I have looked at are:

Write a separate function for the distance. A lot of extra work for when I want both of them.

- Create a custom struct for this one function. *Seems a bit overkill.*
- Return an array like the VBA function did. *Resulting code is not very intuitive, and requires care when using.*
- Using an optional argument as a reference to a variable to store the distance. *Does not work. The compiler does not allow me to change an optional argument.*
- Using an argument list like this `function(const argin1, const argin2, argout&, argout2&)`. *Just ugh! Would require the user to always expect every variable out.*

I have seen examples with pairs, but the they look like they have to be the same data type. I essentially want to return a `point3D`, and a `double`.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution to returning multiple values from a function?

Comment: `std::pair` or `std::tuple` can be used for this. Although usually if you need to return multiple things they are related in some way, in which case defining your own class starts to make sense.

Comment: Use an optional argument, which is a pointer to the distance variable and it's default value is NULL. If it's NULL, do not make any calculation, if it's other than NULL, store the distance in the variable pointed by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to define a custom struct or class, I assume that you want the return value to be only point. So, I suggest you to use an optional pointer argument, it's default value is NULL, and if it is not NULL you store the distance in the variable pointed by it.

```
point3D findIntersect(const vec3 &v1, const vec3 &v2, double *dist = NULL) {
  // ...
  if (dist) {
    // find the distance and store in *dist
  }
  return ... ;
}
```

Comment: This solution covers most of my gripes. It will:  - a) Let me use or not use the length at my own discretion. - b) Let me conditionaly execute necessary code. Thank you all for informative answers!

Comment: Here is roughly what I ended up With:

Comment: <pre>
struct vec3
{
 double x, y, z;
};

struct point3D
{
 double x, y, z;
};

point3D findIntersect(const vec3& vector1, const vec3& vector2, double *dist = NULL)
{
 point3D pointOut;

 pointOut.x = 1;
 pointOut.y = 2;
 pointOut.z = 3;

 if (dist){
  // Only executes if needed
  *dist = 5;
 }

 return pointOut;
}

void main()
{
 vec3 tv1, tv2;
 double length = 0;

 point3D tPoint = findIntersect(tv1, tv2);

 tPoint = findIntersect(tv1, tv2, &length);

 std::cout << tPoint.x << "," << tPoint.y << "," << tPoint.z << std::endl;
 std::cout << "Length: " << length << std::endl;
} <code>

Answer (score 1):

C++ lets you overload the function, i.e. use the same name, but different parameter types. You can return `point3D` as the return value, and make the `length` reference parameter appear "optional" by providing a separate overload:

```
point3D findIntersect(const vec3& vector1, const vec3& vector2) {
    double ignore;
    return findIntersect(vector1, vector2, ignore);
}
point3D findIntersect(const vec3& vector1, const vec3& vector2, double &length) {
    ... // Implementation goes here
}
```

Callers who don't want to get the length back would call the two-argument overload, while the callers who want the length would call the three-argument one. In both cases the implementation is going to be the same, with the two-argument call providing a reference to an ignored variable for the length.

Answer (score 1):

Straustrup and Sutter are recommending using `tuple/tie` for this: [F.41: Prefer to return tuples to multiple out-parameters](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f41-prefer-to-return-tuples-to-multiple-out-parameters)

```
Point3D point3D;
double distance;

std::tie(point3D, distance) = findIntersect(/*..params..*/);
```

Where:

```
std::tuple<Point3D, double> findIntersect(/*..params..*/)
{
    Point3D point3D;
    double distance;

    // calculate point3D & distance

    return std::make_tuple(point3D, distance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `std::pair<point3D, double>`. There is also a `std::tuple`, when you need to return more than two values. (Notice there is no such thing as same type for the pair or tuple values, as you mentioned.)

Answer (score 0):

You sure can use [pairs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/).

```
std::pair<point3D, double> findIntersect(const vec3& vector1, const vec3& vector2);
```

Answer (score -2):

I still think that you can and should create the struct for your code (if your code is not a real time..) Stucts are very common and gives you robastics and flexibility in case you would need to expend your code. To be depends on on these key value pair in you code and then realize after few months that you need to change it in 10 places... :)